# Drink a whole iced capp

Tags: food

Tim Hortons offers a drink called an [iced capp](https://www.timhortons.com/ca/en/menu/iced-capp.php)<sup>1</sup> that behaves in a most infuriating way. No doubt similar concoctions are available to those who live outside the true north strong and free.

The iced capp is partly in liquid and partly in solid state. It is drunk through a straw.<sup>2</sup> By the time one gets to the bottom, at a normal rate of drinking, even on a hot day, one has extracted the liquid and encounters an undrinkably solid remnant that, moreover, leads to more and more "slurping" noise as you near the end of the drink.

Presumably one could wait an hour or however long it takes for it to melt. But this is not ideal. One solution is to constantly stir as you drink.<sup>3</sup> However, even frantically stirring between sips doesn't entirely remove the blockage, and it requires two hands, which is often impractical. I also just tried stirring in some milk after I got home in an attempt to melt or dissolve the dregs, with no luck.

Is there any better solution?

[image: iced capp]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The temptation to write "ice cap", in line with pronunciation, is almost insurmountable even though I know it's wrong.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Mea culpa.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> This requires removing the lid with its narrow aperture, for some reason not pictured on the Tims product page.</sub>

Comment: The same issue would apply to what most Americans know as a "frappucino" or even to a "Slurpee" or "Icee".

Comment: One solution is to skip the straw and drink it directly with your mouth by tipping the glass. However, I'm not posting this as an answer because you specifically say it's drunk with a straw.

Comment: @BrettFromLA I would consider that an acceptable solution, except for one thing: somehow or other, it's too thick to comfortably sip. Reflecting on the paradox of it being drunk from a straw despite that, I think this phenomenon is actually related to the heart of the problem. The straw extracts the liquid, leaving the solid. This might be a good track to follow... for example, adding milk to make it thin enough to sip, and then using that less problematic method.

Comment: In that case, buy the 2% semi-skimmed version.

Comment: @WeatherVane Good suggestion! I'll try that next time I let myself have one of these (the health content being the nugget of truth in Stan's answer...)

Comment: @Luke is this different from [Snow cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_cone)? If so, how?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Not just Americans. Frapps are universal to anywhere there's a Starbucks, including here in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

I know exactly what you're talking about.  When I used to drink those sugary, icy drinks I would try to warm them in my hands and drink them slowly, but usually I wasn't slow enough and there was some residue in the bottom.

I haven't had a drink like that in a while, and I don't intend to (less sugar in my diet), but I'm going to suggest an approach I haven't tried: microwave the drink to speed up the warming process.  I can imagine a Horton's worker willing to pop it in the microwave for a few seconds.  Some stores (not Horton's though?) make microwaves available to customers.

You might also look at other ways of heating the drink quickly.  There are insulated soup mugs that you could pour hot/boiling water into and bring with you, then fit the iced capp into the mug to warm the bottom of the Iced Capp.  Or you could order a hot cappuccino to mix with the iced capp.  That might be a lot of caffeine, though, because IIRC Horton's doesn't have decaf cappucino.  Maybe even hot water would work, I'm sure they'd happily provide you a cup of hot water for a small fee.  :-)

Putting it all together: order a medium/large iced capp and and large/extra large hot water.  Pour most of the hot water out, then put the iced capp cup into the hot water cup.  Enjoy

Answer (score -4):

Consume what you can and or wish. It doesn't matter. As soon as it is difficult to consume easily or comfortably, discard the product.

Everything you see in the photo is/are undigestible plastic by-products. There is no beneficial nutritional value remaining. There was no significant beneficial nutritional value in the "product" you purchased even *before* you accepted and paid for it.

The cup, the top, the straw, and the residue, etc. should be discarded as non-recyclable environmentally undesirable plastic materials

Comment: Why post an answer if you are just gonna tell him not to do what he wants to do?